# Simple MySQL Command to update one row for all tables

Tags: mysql

I need help with a simply (I hope) SQL command.  I need to update one row for all tables.  For example there is one field that I need to change for all tables.

If I manually change the field I receive a response:

```
UPDATE  `mpsadmin_db1`.`website_owner` SET  `iWOPlanId` =  '6' WHERE  `website_owner`.`iWOwnerId` =134;
```

This command updates iWOwnerId 134.

But I need to update the iWOPlanId for all iWOwnerId.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you need to update every row in one table? Or one row in several table?

Comment: Sorry I am am not proficient in mysql, so my explanation may be a little unclear.  The DB is 'mpsadmin_db1' and there is a table 'website_owner'. If I click on that (through phpmyadmin) I see several records and one of the records is `iWOPlanId`.  I can manually change that field to '6' and it works for that single record, but I need to change it to '6' for all tables in 'website_owner'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: Doing the below can change a lot of data very easily.  Be careful!**

If you want to update all rows in the table to have the iWOPlanId of 6, then you can just leave off the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE  `mpsadmin_db1`.`website_owner` SET  `iWOPlanId` =  '6'
```

Some applications (like MySQL Workbench*) won't let you do this (to protect you) so you can get a similar result by doing:

```
UPDATE  `mpsadmin_db1`.`website_owner` SET  `iWOPlanId` =  '6' WHERE  `website_owner`.`iWOwnerId` > 0;
```

*it will if you change the settings

Comment: Good point. Another trick would be `where 1=1` as an always true clause. Has the advantage of being independent of the actual table.

Comment: @PerlDog yeah, the 1=1 trick is a valid alternative.  I'm not a fan of it because it's too easy a statement to put in, where as something like `field > 0` makes you think a tiny bit about what field would cover all circumstances, and therefore hopefully make you think about the query being executed

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to change every row in one table, just omit the "where" clause:

Updates only one row in the table website_owner (the one *where the id is 134*, thus the name of the clause):

```
UPDATE  `mpsadmin_db1`.`website_owner` 
   SET  `iWOPlanId` =  '6' 
 WHERE  `website_owner`.`iWOwnerId` =134;
```

Updates *all* rows in the table website_owner:

```
UPDATE  `mpsadmin_db1`.`website_owner` 
   SET  `iWOPlanId` =  '6';
```